# How do local variables And scope work in java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, variables, scope

I'm confused with this example:

```
        int a = 0;
        
        for(int a = 0;a<5;a++) {
            
        }
        
        System.out.println(a);
```

This example rise an Error (Exception Duplicate local variable a)

```
        for(int a = 0;a<5;a++) {
            
        }
        
        int a = 0;
        
        System.out.println(a);
```

But this one not WHY!

Comment: In `for (int a = 0; ...) {...}`, the `a` will be scoped to the `for` loop's block (the trailing `{...}`), and not accessible outside of the loop. The first example has `int a` already declared, so the loop cannot redeclare `int a` again.

Answer (score 1):

In the first code block, you define `a` which is with scope for the method, so in the loop, you can't define it again. In the second block, you define the first `a` in the loop block scope(only for the loop), so the second definition is possible outside the loop